# How to take backups resilient to data corruption , fast and reliable on Linux?

Tags: linux, backup, raid, mdadm, tar

I need a resilient backup solution. I was using tar with pigz, however I am afraid of tar.gz corruption and losing data. Projects are between 4TB - 25TB of data for each project folder. We are talking about a total of 240TB to 400TB data with incoming projects ... I am also responsible of setting up multiple fileservers with both HW and SW raid and SSD caches. And it is getting started to be spooky :).

I have some ideas but I need your help, advice and critical evaluations of this ideas. Or you may straightforwardly give me another route to solve this. Thank you for reading so far and for your contribution in advance.

Ideas:

- First I will get the file list with sizes du -a and then calculate to bin them into 4GB chunks. Then I tar these file lists with multiple processes using gzip (or pigz ? or lzma?). I hope so that I wont lose more than 4GB per tar.gz corruption. Then I will crc all files one by one also tar.gz files and dump them to compare in the future to check for file corruption.
- I need to keep 2 working raid servers synced. Hopefully rsync will
  handle that each night servers are producing 1 TB data daily at max
  ... Active Work Server have hardware raid 1 with 3x megasas Raid 2108
  devices 3*8 Raid 1 volume and then using mdadm raid 0 I will stripe
  them so that I get raid 10 then I will add SDD mdadm raid 0 caches
  with bcache on top of them. Will this system be hotswappable with
  help of megasas raid 2108 devices ? Second server would be a raid 60
  version of the same 3 x raid 0 of (8 disk Raid6) without cache ...

  SV-1 (Speed) : bcache( (3 x (8x10TB megasas 2108 Raid1) mdadm Raid0 ) + (2x512GB SSD mdadm Raid0) )

  SV-2 (Space) : 3 x (8x10TB megasas 2108 Raid6) mdadm Raid0
- I simulated some scenarios on vmware and qemu - writing over one of the raid disks to corrupt data , deleting-moving disk file (ejecting instantly). So far it doesn't seem great in terms successful rebuilding - recovering. I hope hw raid card will make a difference. I will try on real machine ...

So I have this mess, to be honest which I actually enjoy. Could you help me alleviate some of pressure. Because I read lots of things some says some version of gzip is bugged. Others say xz is not compression format but a container format and it does not abide UNIX philosophy of doing one thing good. Some say raids are not backup (I agree) and there can be silent bit corruptions. Some others say raid cannot rebuild itself if you don't mark some drives at hot spares.

These are very serious articles and some of them are even academic ... There is also some stack overflow and serverfault pages among them.

The point is that data is very important to us.

Comment: What I need to know is a general wisdom setting backup systems on raid servers. 
So if ask it that way it seems more unfocused and vague, without describing the situation what I am in. I tried to be concrete instead of abstract. Should I seperate tar.gz stable backup and raid server questions ? Would it be more focused ?

Answer (score 1):

Gzip are very stable itself but it's just a compression and won't do backup alone.

And tar are just archiving software. It just doesn't do all the things that backup requires in modern environment alone.

You might want to check out some software especially designed for backups which will provide things like data consistency and other.